# Joomla 2.5 Admin showing blank.

Tags: php, xampp, joomla2.5

everybody, I need help , please see this site http://doubleedgetechnologies.com.ng/inmar/

you can also try to access the admin section by clicking here http://doubleedgetechnologies.com.ng/inmar/administrator/

when you load the admin page, it will be blank, and if you look at the title of the admin page, it shows jAdministration.

Please this has happened to all joomla 2.5 website on my local host also,

please how do I fix it?

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Gonna go ahead and jump the gun on this one: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: You are wrong, no space above any of the php files, and no error is displayed too, and i have turned error reporting on...